# Remove columns from matrix by logical array: Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix in Matlab and I want to remove some columns from it. I have also a vector with the indices that I want to remove. How exactly I can do so?

```
train_data   % My input matrix with size 1500x773
toremove     % 1x773 logical vector values (0,1), 1 at 40 indices
```

How can I apply `toremove` to the `train_data` to remove the desired indices?

```
output = train_data(toremove) % I want the output  to be a matrix with size 1500x733
```

Comment: My input is the train_data with that size while the output is a reduced matrix as a matter of columns since I want to remove the indexes that have logical values in toremove equal to 1.

Comment: @SardarUsama is it clear now?

Comment: Sorry for the ignorance but what exactly should I post? I have as an input the train_data and the vector toremove and i want the output to be a reduced matrix, but I dont know how can I apply toremove to the train_data matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to delete columns in 2d matrix based off 1d column matrix:

```
output = train_data(:,find(toremove<1));
```

If it's rows that need deleting instead, based off 1d row matrix:

```
output = train_data(find(toremove<1),:);
```

Might do the job if I understand this correctly.

Comment: Seems yes. Thanks.

Comment: This removes rows instead of columns as asked by the OP. @JoseRamon Is this what you want?

Comment: Oops, I read it wrong, well in that case just invert it; I'll edit my answer

Answer (score 1):

If your array is truly logical (true/false) you can use it directly for indexing, it sounds like it's binary though (0/1), so you can use `logical(toremove)` to convert it to logical, then it's simple:

```
train_data = train_data(:,~logical(toremove));
% or equivalently
train_data(:, logical(toremove)) = [];
```

Avoiding a call to the `find` function will increase speed.

Comment: Exactly what I was going to post.

Comment: Cheers @Sardar, slowly trying to squeeze `find` habits out of SO users!

Comment: Good point; wasn't sure if OP always had logical values, and so suggested find for scaling up to other numbers.
I get the intent of downvote, but I thought SO reserved it for answers not being useful. OP clearly did find it useful...

Comment: @mehfoosyacoob I don't agree with the downvote though

Comment: @mehfoosyacoob I didn't downvote, it is for Qs/As which aren't useful, yours is just not optimal, achieves the same result :)